# Can not access payment methods tab in magento back office

Tags: admin, error, paypal, payment, methods

I installed the last version available of Magento 1.9.2.1.
I try to access the payment methods tab as an admin and I have this error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function setAllowedTypes() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magentomerchant\app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Config.php on line 1092**

I did not modify any of the core modules of magento.
Any explanations ?

[image]

Thank you

**Edit:**

It seems that as soon as I add a new module I have this error.
This is its config.xml

0.1.0

```
  <frontend>
    <routers>
        <payment>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Merchant_Payment</module>
                <frontName>payment</frontName>
            </args>
        </payment>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <payment>
                <file>payment.xml</file>
            </payment>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <payment>
            <class>Merchant_Payment_Block</class>
        </payment>
    </blocks>


    <models>
        <payment>
            <class>Merchant_Payment_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>payment_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </payment>
        <payment_mysql4>
            <class>Merchant_Payment_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>

                <payment>
                    <table>transaction_test</table>
                </payment>

                <magentoservice>
                    <table>magento_service</table>
                </magentoservice>

                <magentotransaction>
                    <table>magento_transaction</table>
                </magentotransaction>

            </entities>
        </payment_mysql4>
     </models>
    <!-- Fin Déclaration model -->
    <resources>
        <payment_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </payment_write>
        <payment_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </payment_read>
    </resources>
</global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <payment>
            <use>admin</use>>
            <args>
                <module>Merchant_Payment</module>
                <frontName>payment</frontName>
            </args>
        </payment>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: Make sure you have Mage_Payment_Model_Source_Cctype class exist.

Check file app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Model\Source\Cctype.php

Comment: Indeed, I just checked and it does exist

Comment: It might be possible some files are missing in your setup. restore your core files if you have fresh setup.

Comment: I removed a new module that I added and also restored the initial config and now it works fine. I do not know what's wrong with the stuff that I added. As soon I find I post it. Thank you

Comment: It seems that as soon as I add a new module I have this error. I added its  config.xml file in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with your model class declaration

```
<models>
        <payment>
            <class>Merchant_Payment_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>payment_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </payment>
      ..........
```

change it to

```
<models>
            <merchant_payment>
                <class>Merchant_Payment_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>payment_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </merchant_payment>
......
```

And it should work.

Comment: It works fine. Thanks. 
What was wrong with this decleration ? Because the module works fine when I acces the url that I defined for the front end but I have a problem only when I try to acces the payment methods tab in the admin panel.